Sound Issue: Headphones Output Sound from Both Headphones and Speakers on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I’m experiencing an issue with audio on my Ubuntu 24.04.1 system running on a Huawei BOD-WXX9. When I plug in my headphones, sound continues to come from both the headphones and the speakers. However, when I connect a Bluetooth headset, the sound only comes from the Bluetooth headset, which works fine.
